# The method setMultiChoiceItems(int, boolean[], DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener) in the type AlertDialog.Builder is not applicable

Tags: android

I am trying to build an dynamic dialog window  in my onNewIntent method for any Integer ArrayList for example [1,9,13] but I am getting at this line `builder.setMultiChoiceItems` this error"

> The method setMultiChoiceItems(int, boolean[],
>   DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener) in the type
>   AlertDialog.Builder is not applicable for the arguments
>   (ArrayList, null, new
>   DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener(){})

I appreciate any help.

onNewIntent method:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    setIntent(intent);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {

        ArrayList<Integer> routeList = extras
                .getIntegerArrayList("stop_route");
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.setTitle("Select");

        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(routeList, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {


            }
        });
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    }
                });


        builder.create();
        builder.show();

    }

}
```

Comment: `setMultiChoiceItems()` requires as first parameter an `int` not a `List<Integer>` 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html

Comment: Your first argument ArrayList<Integer> doesn't match. There is no setMultiChoiceItems function with an ArrayList as input. Maybe you meant the resource id of an string array? That has to be in the xml files then. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html

Comment: @sebastian: does that mean I need to loop through my ArrayList? if yes where?

Comment: @IdleGandalf: in the onNewIntent I am getting an arrayList<Integer> which I want to display in Dialog window. Why do I need the xml file?

Comment: @TheTime You don't have to use an xml file, but then you need to convert your Arraylist<Integer> into an CharSequence Array, to match this method definition: setMultiChoiceItems (CharSequence[] items, boolean[] checkedItems, DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener listener)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
public AlertDialog.Builder setMultiChoiceItems (CharSequence[] items, boolean[] checkedItems, DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener listener)
```

just convert your `ArrayList<Interger>` to an `CharSequence[]`,

Convert:

```
ArrayList<Integer> routeList = extras.getIntegerArrayList("stop_route");
CharSequence charSequence [] = new CharSequence[routeList.size()];
for(int i = 0, size = routeList.size(); i < size; i++){
    charSequence[i] = String.valueOf(routeList.get(i));
}

builder.setMultiChoiceItems(charSequence, null, new Dia ..........
```

Comment: I have converted it to CharSequence like this  `  builder.setMultiChoiceItems(CharSequence[]  cs, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener()`  but I am getting this error `Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)`

Comment: Sebastian the app crashs and I am getting `java.lang.ArrayStoreException: source[0] of type java.lang.Integer cannot be stored in destination array of type java.lang.CharSequence[]`